# Including input statements and conditions in the make file

Tags: c, ubuntu, makefile

I am trying to create a makefile, for the first time. I went through some tutorials and I managed to create one, but I am having trouble with a couple of things. Below are the details.

Below are the files in the order of execution:

1. `CSV_to_txt.c` - no dependency on any other files.

[image]

I want to include `CSV_files/Equilibrium_trajectories.csv`, which is my input, in the make file. Further, I run the command  `tac Chemical_Equilibrium.txt` in the terminal. Can I include this in the make file as well?

2. `fluid_profile.c` - depends on `pdfutil.h` and `beta_util.h`.

I have the same problem of reading the inputs, for ex:

`Enter the number of points`

`1000` --> to be included in the make file.

This file creates a text file called `fluid_points.txt`. What I want to include in the makefile is if this file already exists don't execute the command `gcc fluid_points.c -o fluid_points.o -lm`.

Structure of the make file:

```
all:
     gcc CSV_to_txt.c -o CSV_to_txt.o -lm
     ./CSV_to_txt.o
     #Include the file path and name when asked for it

     #ubuntu terminal command --> tac filename.txt > filename_changed.txt

     gcc fluid_profile.c -o fluid_profile.o -lm
     ./fluid_profile.o
     #Enter the number of points when prompted to do so

     #If fluid_points.txt file is already existing don't execute the above command, instead execute the below one

     gcc blah.c -o blah.o -lm
     ./blah.o

clean:
     $(RM) *.o *~
```

Any sort of help or even a link to a tutorial would be helpful.

Comment: Using `.o` as filename extension for an executable isn't recommended - is there a thorough idea behind this breaking of conventions?

Comment: In fact, I was using `exe` for executable. But I saw more and more people using `.o` files and I started using it. I didn't really question it.

Comment: The 'o' stands for 'object file' which is generally understood as being a non-executable binary format which is input to the linking process, which in turn produces the executable. If you saw that in use frequently, I think you mistook it - those people were producing just object files for later linking.

Comment: I don't know much about the linking process, I understood this though. The linker combines all object files into one executable. But how do you create this linker? I am not even sure if creating a linker is the right question? Let me know if I am wrong. @Vroomfondel

Comment: The linker is a program which is usually coming with the rest of your toolchain like the C++ compiler or binary utility programs. GCC hides the invocation of its linker `ld` behind the software construction process `gcc`. If you have a C/C++ program with function `main` in it, then `gcc` behind the curtain produces the corresponding object file and immediately links it to a complete executable. I recommend you to skim the relevant topics at least superficially before continueing with `make` as this will accelerate your understanding much more than trying to grasp the sw build process via make.

Comment: I will do that, thanks @Vroomfondel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggested makefile:

```
run:

.PHONY: run

CSV_to_txt: CSV_to_txt.c
     gcc CSV_to_txt.c -o CSV_to_txt -lm

fluid_profile: fluid_profile.c
     gcc fluid_profile.c -o fluid_profile -lm

blah: blah.c
     gcc blah -o blah.c -lm

run: CSV_to_txt fluid_profile blah
     echo "CSV_files/Equilibrium_trajectories.csv" | ./CSV_to_txt.o 
     tac Chemical_Equilibrium.txt
     echo "1000" | ./fluid_profile.o
     ./blah.o

clean:
     $(RM) *.o *~
```

So, a break down -- first line, predeclare target `run`, such that it becomes the default target (if you do `make`, it will run the first target ).   Declare this as a phony target (This means there's no actual file called `run` being produced.   You can look up [`.PHONY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) for more details)

Then create some rules to generate the executables.  Each executable has its own rule to generate it.   Typically you would use [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) for these like `$@` and `$<`, but I wanted to keep it simple for now.

Then the rule for `run`.   This is dependent on the executables (so executables will finish building before this rule runs).

Then, to pass the filename into the executable, you can simply `echo` the filename, and then [pipe](https://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/piping.php) that into the executable.

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thank you for explaining it as well. One more question, is there a way I can time this run? @HardcoreHenry

Comment: you can run `time make` which will show the runtime etc  after make completes.

Answer (score 1):

You have a common newbie error... this is to think that a source file depends on other source files (a `.c` file depends on some `.h` files)  This is an error and probably the cause you are not getting your result.

The objective of a `Makefile` is to describe file dependencies in order to do the minimum set of commands to build the final target you specify.  For this you need to think that a target is something you are goint to create.

Is a source `.c` file something you create during the build proces? Not, so it cannot be a target of a rule.  The target, indeed is the result of the compilation.  The source file doesn't depend on a header file... it just includes it to make the compilation of the `.o` target (this is, actually the target).

Let's say you have a program `hello.c` that includes `modA.h` and `modB.h`.  (and even `modB.h` includes `modB2.h`)  If you modify any of them, **you need to recompile `hello.c`,** so your rule will be:

```
# (1)
hello.o: hello.c modA.h modB.h modB2.h
    cc -c hello.c                 # (2) see below.
```

- (1) a rule line starts at column 1 and has a left hand side (the target file) and a list of sources (dependencies).  Each time make sees that the target doesn't exist or has a last change date earlier than the change dates of any of the dependencies, the command lines below are executed, one after the other.
- (2) a command rule starts with a `<tab>` char in the first column of the line.  It represents a command (or a list of commands, each in it's command line) that are required to generate the target file from the sources.
- a line starting with `#` is a comment line (also valid to start in the middle of a rule or a command line)
- There is anothe type of line (a macro definition) but you need to learn first how to create dependencies and get used to them, before starting learning how to create macros.  Read the `make(1)` doc first.
  you see that we only compile `hello.c`, but we have to do it every time we change any of the other files above.  There are two modules, `modA.o` and `modB.o`, each of them with their `.c` file and the includes needed in `hello.c`.  So:

```
modA.o: modA.c modA.h
    cc -c modA.c
modB.o: modB.c modB.h modB2.h
    cc -c modB.c
```

so when we change any of `modA.c` or `modA.h` then `modA.o` will be created.  And as `modB.h` we said above that included `modB2.h`, then if we modify it, it should be compiled.

Now the dependency of the program to be linked:  As the program is compiled, it has just three modules: `hello.o`, `modA.o` and `modB.o`.  To create `hello` all these three modules must be given to the linker.... so the Makefile needs also:

```
hello: hello.o modA.o modB.o
    cc -o hello hello.o modA.o modB.o
```

and so, the complete `Makefile` is:

```
# this rule is put first to become the default target.
# the default target is the final program.
hello: hello.o modA.o modB.o
    cc -o hello hello.o modA.o modB.o

# this rule is for the hello.o target only.
hello.o: hello.c modA.h modB.h modB2.h
    cc -c hello.c

# this rule is for modA.o
modA.o: modA.c modA.h
    cc -c modA.c

# and this one for modB.o
modB.o: modB.c modB.h modB2.h
    cc -c modB.c
```

and with this `Makefile` you'll enjoy, because you can touch any file, but the compiler will compile only the correct dependencies to generate the final executable program.

Make has a lot of more functionality, but that requires you to know at least the most basic of it.  Once after you have succeeded on the creation of the correct dependencies, you can start to study the other facilities of make, that are only there to abbreviate/avoid rewritting the same thing several times.  But read at least the make manual page.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful "tutorial". This really helped. I will take a look into the make manual page as you suggested. @Luis Colorado

Comment: @UdayCK, If you are happy with this answer, you had better to select it as _the answer_.